# pass variable from js code to flask in db or something like

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I'm brand-new in English, Python and Flask, and I'm sorry if I write really bad things.

I have the following task: when a user go to `pfofile.html`, the page is loaded with a value from the database.
If the user changes the color, then the JavaScript function is started (`onchange()` is called).
I have to write the code that changes the field `text_color_in_chat` in database.
I thought that I did all right, but I have the following error: `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 't' is undefined`.
And I don't understand how I can pass the "t" variable from JavaScript to Python using Flask, or how to properly call the braces shackle `{{}}`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function change_color(t) {
    alert( {{ current_user.change_color_in_db(t.value) }} );
}
</script>
<div>
    Check your color in chat:
    <input type="color" value="{{ user.text_color_in_chat }}" onchange="change_color(this);">
</div>
```

Here is a piece of my `models.py`:

```
...
text_color_in_chat = db.Column(db.String(8), default='#000000')
...
def change_color_in_db(self, new_color):
        # re.search(r'^#[0-9a-f]{6,6}$', "#000000"
        self.text_color_in_chat = new_color
        db.session.add(self)
        return True
...
```

And in my Python function, I'm testing the variable `new_color` with a RegEx. If it does not match it returns `None`, else it returns the object. And, I don't understand how to use a `if` condition.

Comment: Your English is not very good, but I do my best to translate your question. I think I have understand what you want. Just tell me if it's unclear.

Comment: how i can change field in database from js function "change_color()"?

Comment: and about RegEx i want to now how correctly to create condition if re.search(r'^#[0-9a-f]{6,6}$', str): change data in db else: not change and alert about error str. where "str" is expected color code in hexadecimal form.

Comment: wau, you correct my errors in question, thank you, may be now answer will be quickly found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see and understand the way a client/server application work:

From the user's browser:

1. the user enter a value in a form;
2. the user submit the form;
3. the form data is posted to the server and wait for the response.

On the server:

1. the server get the HTTP request and decode it;
2. the URL is translated into a "route";
3. the server call the function or method attached to the route;
4. the function do it's job and must return a HTTP response (data + status code);
5. the response (more often a HTML page) is sent back to the browser.

On the user's browser:

1. the browser render the HTML page (or other kind of data);
2. the user can then continue it's browsing.

… and the loop is done.

**From the user's browser:**

What you want is a way to register the user's change to database.

To do that, you can use a classic HTML form or an Ajax request. Since your are using JavaScript, an Ajax request is the best way to do that. For instance, you can use [`jQuery.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to do that:

Here is a draft:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function change_color(t) {
    var url = "/route/to/change_color";
    var data = {color: $('#chat-color').val()};
    $.post(url, data);
}
</script>
```

This code get the value of the `input` field which *id* is `#chat-color` and post it to the URL "/route/to/change_color".

Of course, you need th change your HTML form like this to add the `#chat-color` *id*:

```
<div>
    Check your color in chat:
    <input id="chat-color" type="color" value="{{ user.text_color_in_chat }}" onchange="change_color(this);">
</div>
```

**On the server:**

You need to define a function for the route "/route/to/change_color".

The function could be:

```
import re
from flask import request

@app.route('/route/to/change_color', methods=['POST'])
def change_color():
    new_color = request.form['color']
    if re.match(r'^#[0-9a-f]{6,6}$', new_color):
        self.text_color_in_chat = new_color
        db.session.add(self)
        ...
    ...
```

Here is a small solution which use a global variable instead of a database (to keep it simple):

```
# coding: utf8
import json
import re
import textwrap

from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

text_color_in_chat = "#000000"


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    content = textwrap.dedent("""\
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function change_color(t) {
        var url = "/route/to/change_color";
        var data = {color: $('#chat-color').val()};
        $.post(url, data);
    }
    </script>
    <div>
        Check your color in chat:
        <input id="chat-color" type="color" value="<color>" onchange="change_color(this);">
    </div>
    """)
    return content.replace("<color>", text_color_in_chat)


@app.route('/route/to/change_color', methods=['POST'])
def change_color():
    new_color = request.form['color']
    if re.match(r'^#[0-9a-f]{6,6}$', new_color):
        global text_color_in_chat
        text_color_in_chat = new_color
        return json.dumps({'change_color': "OK"})
    return json.dumps({'change_color': "Invalid color"})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: thank you very much, after I wrote the question, I started to think about Ajax, but not knew how do it correctly and now I understand))